# Was there a lack of unity at Har Sinai?

Tags: har-sinai

Rabbi Lord Sacks mentions in his book [here](https://www.rabbisacks.org/covenant-conversation/vayakhel/the-spirit-of-community/#:%7E:text=What%20Moses%20had%20to%20do%20after%20the%20Golden%20Calf%20was%20Vayakhel%20%E2%80%93%20turn%20the%20Israelites%20into%20a%20kehillah%2C%20a%20community.)

> "What Moses had to do after the Golden Calf was Vayakhel – turn the Israelites into a kehillah, a community."

Question: What happened and where is it discussed, between the Jews being encamped by the mountain in unison, until the need for Moshe to bring them together after the golden calf?

Where is is discussed the details of the lack of unity and possibly what had caused it?

Comment: https://inner.org/parashat-ki-tisa-understanding-the-sin-of-the-golden-calf/

Comment: The Golden Calf itself was a very divisive event. Your link is broken btw.

Comment: @shmosel can you please elaborate on it being divisive, or point me where to look (link has been corrected)

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.32.27?lang=bi